# How to auto start script on boot on Raspbian OS Buster?

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, autostart

This doesn't make one bit sense to me at all. I used to auto start scripts on Jessie Raspbian OS on Pi 3 very easily. All I did was either copy my script into `/home/pi/.config/autostart/myscript.sh` or use `crontab` and added `@reboot -H /home/pi/myscript.sh`. And the script will run on boot with no problem. None of the above technique works at all on the latest Raspbian Buster. However, if I directly double-click on the script, it works or runs as expected.

I recently upgraded Raspbian OS Jessie to Buster and no matter what I do to get my script to autostart, it won't run.

1.) Created AutoStart folder within `/home/pi/.config/autostart` and stored a copy of my script in the autostart folder. It won't run at boot.

2.) Created Autostart folder within `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/autostart and a copy of my script in this autostart folder. It won't run at boot. In fact, on the next boot Raspbian Buster logged me out. I couldn't even get on to the Desktop. So, I had to delete that folder. Then, it let me into the Desktop.

3.) I created `Crontab` like so `@reboot -H /home/pi/myscript.sh` and still it refuses to run on boot.

4.) I updated `rc.local` by adding the following line `/home/pi/myscript.sh` and still nothing. Won't run.

5.) I even did the `init.d` folder; put a copy of my script into init.d folder, did an update `sudo update-rc.d myscript.sh defaults` and still my script won't run.

6.) I even added the following line in the `.bashrc` `/home/pi/myscript.sh`. Still, my script didn't AUTOSTART on BOOT. However, ONLY when I opened my Konsole or Terminal, my script did run.

In case you are wondering, I did do the `chmod +x myscript` prior to doing all of the above.

So, what am doing wrong? This should be very simple unless I am missing something. Any hints or clues will be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:** All I have in my script is the following:

```
#! /bin/sh

cd /home/pi/myproject

sudo /home/pi/myproject/myprogram

exit 0
```

Comment: What init system does buster use? In particular, is it systemd-based? (I would expect it to be if the distro is modern, which would explain `rc.local` and other SysV-init-specific approaches not being supported except through optional compatibility shims).

Comment: BTW, `@reboot` is an fcron feature. It's not something standard Vixie cron has ever supported. (Not that I know which version of cron Buster uses, but if you're relying on a niche feature, it's worth knowing _exactly_ which cron you have).

Comment: Also, importantly, have you tested that your script _actually works_ when it's run from a noninteractive environment? It's a very common mistake for folks to write scripts that require their `.bash_profile` or such to work; but that's only invoked in login shells, so any script started by cron / sytemd / etc. won't see variables set there.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, it is systemd

Comment: That being the case, have you tried setting up a systemd service? That is, with a `.service` file describing how to run your script?

Comment: yes, my script does run on noninteractive environment. This script is the very same one that I used on Jessie and it ran on it at boot with no issue.

Comment: The other thing I'd do is to instrument your script so it logs execution. Making the second line something like `[ -t 2 ] || { exec 2>/tmp/myscript.log.$$; set -x; }` and then looking for `/tmp/myscript.log*` files would help you find problems if it _is_ trying to run but just failing due to not having expected content from your `.profile` or similar.

Comment: No I didnt. Should I have done that?

Comment: Yes, you should create a `.service` file if you want to run a script on boot on a systemd-based distro. See docs @ https://manpages.debian.org/buster/systemd/systemd.service.5.en.html, or https://wiki.debian.org/systemd

Comment: (systemd also obsoletes cron, replacing crontab entries with `.timer` units that periodically start any `.service` with the same name).

Comment: okay something to try... Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60941648/systemd-service-not-starting-on-boot-starts-when-i-restart-it, where someone is asking about a problem encountered while doing the thing I recommend you do (and describing how they did it, along the way).

Comment: unfortunately, systemd doesn't work either. I have NO CLUE why it just won't execute my script at boot.

Comment: Fortunately, when systemd "doesn't work", it generates logs. Lots of them. Good ones.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236360/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-thn).

Comment: It's too bad this question is closed. I just literally solved my issue and I was hoping to post an answer for this question to help others.

Comment: If you can describe the solution, I can determine whether that solution is already given on any duplicates. If it isn't, then we can probably find a way to edit the question to no longer appear duplicative and reopen it (or if the question is duplicative but the answer is unique, you can add that solution on such a duplicate, if it isn't already given on one of them).

Comment: BTW, since you edited in the script... might I guess that you needed to clear the `requiretty` flag in sudoers? (Or even better would be to make the script run directly as root so you never need sudo in the first place). None of that is new/unique/not-already-covered-in-the-knowledgebase-elsewhere.

Comment: (Also, I'd suggest using `exec ./myprogram` and taking out the `exit` -- that way the shell will stop running at all after the subprocess is up, making for a cleaner process tree and allowing signals to be directly delivered to `myprogram` instead of having them go to the shell that _started_ `myprogram`; makes a lot of things cleaner that way).

Comment: Just add the following line to /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
`sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`
@/home/pi/myproject/myprogram

Comment: So this is a _graphical_ program?! You should have said that up-front! You can't start things that need GUI-framework tools unless you make them wait for your GUI framework to be available.

Comment: Anyhow -- I replaced the duplicate with one that's on-target given the underlying problem (a problem this question did not contain enough information to diagnose, even as-edited, since nothing in it even _hinted_ at your program running a GUI).